# Here is my source code of a page. I need to click on a "infoview" element Any suggestions how to do this using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is my HTML source code of a page. I need to click on a "infoview" element. Any suggestions how to do this using selenium webdriver?

```
<a href="javascript:showDocumentList()">
<IMG style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none" src="/InfoViewApp/res/general/btn_Infoview.gif"></a>
```

Comment: <a href="javascript:showDocumentList()"><IMG style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none" src="/InfoViewApp/res/general/btn_Infoview.gif"></a>

Comment: Show us what you have tried? xpath? What's your approach?

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the image")).click();

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/InfoViewApp/res/general/btn_Infoview.gif']")).click();
```

make sure that the image is pointing to the right source.